# How to Code that Dont Accept Data if its already in the table for NAME Column?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to prevent duplication of data when inserting.
this is my code and its not working, I just want to know how to code this properly

```
<input type="text" name="text" id="text" readonyy="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type here for manual inserting" class="form-control" formaction="insert.php" value="<?php if(isset($errors['name'])) echo $errors['n']; ?>" required>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Insert Name</button>
```

```
$name = $_POST['name'];

        $errors = array();

        $n = "SELECT NAME FROM table_attendance WHERE NAME='$name'";
        $nn = mysqli_query($conn,$n);

        if (empty($name)) {
            $errors['n'] = "Value is needed to proceed";
        }elseif (mysqli_num_rows($nn) > 0) {
            $errors['n'] = "This Person already scan his/her QR Code";
        }

        header("Location: index.php");
```

I want to know how to code this properly

Comment: do you have a specific question?

Comment: How to code this properly

Comment: Well, [`mysqli_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) is a function that returns a Boolean on failure, or a result if successful, so I’d start there.

Answer (score -1):

1. Check $_POST['name'] before accessing it
   `if(isset($_POST['name'])`
2. Your inputs name is defined as "text". check it out too

p.s. this my first answer on SO)